# Calculating MySQL and PHP date difference in days

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to calculate a date difference in days using MySQL and PHP date.

**My code**

```
$ArrivalDate = $variants_data['ArrivalDate'];
$daydiff=floor((abs(strtotime(date("d/m/Y")) - strtotime($ArrivalDate))/(60*60*24)));
```

**Output**

```
<td>'.$daydiff.'</td>
```

**Results**
I get 93 days instead of 26 days (got 26 days using this calculator http://easycalculation.com/date-day/number-of-days.php)

**ArrivalDate** value = 2013-05-03 from MySQL table and it changes due to transport delays, etc.

How can I achieve this in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$daydiff=floor((abs(strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) - strtotime($ArrivalDate))/(60*60*24)));
```

just change your current date function format so it will give your correct answer means 26 days.

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime class :

```
$today = new DateTime;
$oneWeekLater = clone $today;
$oneWeekLater->modify('+1 week');

$diff = $today->diff($oneWeekLater);
echo $diff->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$diff = strtotime(date("d/m/Y")) - strtotime($ArrivalDate);
echo "Difference is $diff seconds\n";
$days = floor($diff/(3600*24));
echo "Difference is $days days\n";
```

You can also do it at the database level using the DATEDIFF() function.

http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_datediff_mysql.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
$days = date("d", $timestamp1) - date("d", $timestamp2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ArrivalDate = '2013-05-03';
echo $daydiff=floor((abs(strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) - strtotime($ArrivalDate))/(60*60*24)));
```

Your date function was not in proper format as that of arrival date