# SQL query TIMESTAMPDIFF with php not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I try to take a date and do countdown untill that day like following:

The date i want to countdown to: 2016-05-1 00:00:00

Then i want to calculate the diff between the date and now so i can do countdown timer.

I have this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jerusalem");

if ($result = $db->query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), 2016-05-1 00:00:00)")) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $currentTimeLeft= $row['TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), 2016-05-1 00:00:00)']; 
    }

    echo json_encode($currentTimeLeft);
}
```

I dont understand why this returning empty. What is wrong here?

Comment: This is similar, I wonder whether your question is close enough to be dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877121/calculating-mysql-and-php-date-difference-in-days

Comment: There he not use TIMESTAMPDIFF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see quote issue in your query

try this

```
if($result = $db->query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),'2016-05-1 00:00:00') as datediff")) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $currentTime = $row['datediff']; 
        }

 echo json_encode($currentTime);
```

I have added an alias "datediff" to the result column as well

Comment: You might explain that you have also added an alias to give the result column an easily usable name **try this** is not helpful to others that may read your answer at a later date

Answer (score 0):

you are missing quotes in the query

```
if ($result = $db->query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), '2016-05-1 00:00:00') as t")) {
```